# Should a New Project Use Spring DM 2.0.0.M1 or Gemni Blueprint 1.0.0.M1?

Tags: spring, osgi, eclipse-gemini

I am about to incorporate Spring DM into a bundle that will run in the Apache Karaf OSGi framework. Given that Spring DM is being transitioned to Gemni Blueprint, should I use Spring DM 2.0.0.M1 or start fresh with Gemni Blueprint 1.0.0.M1? Or should I go with the last formal release of Spring DM (1.2.1)? Any thoughts?

---

**UPDATE:**

This could serve as an argument against using Gemni Blueprint:

> As of M1, not all modules or projects
>   inside Spring DM have been moved. At
>   the moment only the io, core, extender
>   and test modules have transitioned are
>   provided in M1. With the up-coming
>   release of OSGi RFC-66, the web
>   support is being discontinued.
>   Existing users are encouraged to look
>   at Eclipse Gemini Web project. The
>   plans for the Maven archetype and
>   annotation extension are undefined for
>   the moment. -- http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/migration/

The fact that not all of the Spring DM modules are included in Gemni Blueprint could make existing documentation difficult to follow. Has anyone tried using Gemni Blueprint and Gemni Web to do the same things that are done with Spring DM?

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring DM has been contributed to the Eclipse Foundation more than 1.5 years ago, I suggest you to go with Gemini Blueprint:

> In late 2009, Spring DM has been contributed to the Eclipse Foundation as the Gemini Blueprint project. All new development is now hosted and released through the Eclipse foundation. Please see the Gemini Blueprint site for details.
>   For more information on the Gemini project and Spring DM donation see the links below:

see [here](http://www.springsource.org/osgi). Documentation for migration from Spring DM [here](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/migration/).

Also you probably should check out [Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/).

Comment: What strikes me odd about this (and part of the reason for my question) is that in 1.5 years, the Eclipse Foundation still has not come out with a formal release. What's more, the documentation for migration states that things are still in transition. It looks as if they took Spring DM 2.0.0.M1, changed the package name, and left it at that.

Comment: Certainly seems so that the project is dead or on hold: https://fisheye.springsource.org/user/cleau (lead dev, commits only in spring-framework since at least february) and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced;order=Importance;product=Gemini.Blueprint, gemini blueprint bugzilla. I'd probably approach them in mail or whatever and ask about the status of the project.

Comment: The latest on the mailing list (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/200332/675992/#msg_675992) says that the GA release of Blueprint will be some time in June.  However, the lack of activity in both code and mailing lists is troubling.